# Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused - Executable file not found

Tags: django, python-3.x, macos, docker, docker-compose

I am following the django tutorial from their web site;

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial02/

I got a problem on this step;

```
python manage.py migrate
```

I am trying to develop the application in a docker container, so when I run the below command;

```
docker-compose run web manage.py migrate
```

I got this error;

```
Starting docker-django-project_db_1 ... done
Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"manage.py\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
```

I tried to add the path of the manage.py directory to $PATH but I am still getting the same error.